# Mac Mini DVI to Dell U271

Tags: display, dvi, mac-mini, high-resolution

I have a MacMini which is a couple of years old now, it has ONLY a DVI connector on the back, no display port.

I recently bought a Dell U271 monitor which is capable of going up to 2560x1440 using a Dual Link DVI cable under Linux.  If I take the same cable and plug it into the Mac Mini, it only goes up to 1920x1080.

Can it go higher?  Or does this question apply: https://discussions.apple.com/message/6672268#6672268 and it's only single dvi out?

Also, switching to a single DVI cable gives me the option of using 2048x1152, but no higher.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I think you are correct in that it can only go single-link. 2560x1440 resolution definitely require a dual-link DVI connection.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick ... but can you expand on the "I think you are correct" please?  I think I'm correct, but I'd like to know from a canonical source so I can stop *trying* to get it to work.  Thanks.

Comment: To put it clearly, GMA950 (Which is used in early intel mac minis) can only support resolution up to a single link DVI connector, which 2048x1536x75Hz. Anything beyond is impossible.

Comment: Thanks bubu, I did a little more reading on the GMA950, that makes sense.  I'm only getting 2048x1152 - I don't suppose you know how I'd get the extra vertical resolution that the GMA is capable of?

Comment: I think that's a 4:3 large monitor to get that resolution. I'm just old enough to have seen such a monitor.

Comment: I'm referring to the DELL U271 in the original question.  It's capable of going up to a resolution of 2560x1440.  How do I get my macmini to display the 2048x1536 that the GMA is capable of doing?  Or is the highest I can go 1152 lines?

Comment: You can only get 1152 lines. The u2711 is a 16:9 monitor.